# Regular expression get filename without extention from full filepath

Tags: regex

How can I extract the filename without extention from the following file path:

```
D:\Projects\Extract\downtown - second.pdf
```

The following regular expression gives me the filename with extention: `[^\\]*$`
e.g. `downtown - second.pdf`
The following regular expression gives me the filename without extention: `(.+)(?=(\.))`
e.g. `D:\Projects\Extract\downtown - second`

I'm struggling to combine the two into one regular expression to give me the results I want: downtown - second

Comment: Didn't you get `downtown-second` in your 2nd regex?

Comment: I'm confused .. you said that the second regex gives you what you want?

Comment: The second regex return everything without the extension.

Comment: @JohnW.Mnisi. Then update your question. You have written wrong output for 2nd regex there.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that your 2nd regex would not give you the output you have shown. It will give you the complete string till the first `period (.)`.

To get just the file name without extension, you can use this regex: -

```
[^\\]*(?=[.][a-zA-Z]+$)
```

I have just replaced `(.+)` in your 2nd regex with the `[^\\]*` from your first regex, and added pattern to match `pdf` till the end.

Now this pattern will match `0 or more` repetition of any character but `backslash(\)`, followed by a `.` and then `1 or more` repetition of alphabets making up extension.

Answer (score 5):

I made up this one, which allows to capture most of the possibilities:

```
/[^\\\/]+(?=\.[\w]+$)|[^\\\/]+$/
```

/path/to/**file**

/path/to/**file**.txt

/path.with/dots.to/**file**.txt

/path/to/**file.with.dots**.txt

**file**.txt

C:\path\to\**file**.txt

and so on...

Comment: Thanks! Used this with multiple match:
`var exp = new RegExp(/[^\\\/]+(?=\.[\w]+$)|[^\\\/]+$/g);
var fileName = exp.exec(filePath)[0];
var fileExtension = exp.exec(filePath)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

I captured file from /path/to/file.pdf by using following regex:

```
[^/]*(?=\.[^.]+($|\?))
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an extra backslash before the first ']' to make this work

```
[^\\\]*(?=[.][a-zA-Z]+$)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern

```
[^\/]+[.+\.].*$  for / path separator
[^\\]+[.+\.].*$  for \ path separator
```

hich matches the filename at the end of the string without worrying about characters. There is one exception that if the path for some reason has a folder with a period in it this will get upset. Linux hidden directories that are preceded with a . like .rvm are unaffected.

Hope this helps.
http://rubular.com/r/LNrI4inMU1