# C# Regex to Get file name without extension?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use regex to get a filename without extension. I'm having trouble getting regex to return a value. I have this:

```
string path = @"C:\PERSONAL\TEST\TESTFILE.PDF";
var name = Regex.Match(path, @"(.+?)(\.[^\.]+$|$)").Value;
```

In this case, `name` always comes back as `C:\PERSONAL\TEST\TESTFILE.PDF`. What am I doing wrong, I think my search pattern is correct?

(I am aware that I could use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);`but I specifically want to try using regex)

Comment: Why use a regex for this when a perfectly good framework method exists?  You can use a regex, but then you'll have an additional problem on your hands.

Comment: but why? looking for [trouble](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems)?

Comment: If this is just for learning regular expressions, then that's fine, but there is absolutely no good reason to use a regular expression for this.  In fact I'd say regular expressions should be your last resort when solving most problems.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is calling a method without looking it up on MSDN first, getting a result you don't expect, and then *still* not bothering to read the documentation. You had no idea what `Regex.Match()` returned, it obviously wasn't what you guessed it might be, so you come here to ask somebody to read the MSDN page out loud to you.

Comment: If MSDN is too scary, run this and stick a breakpoint after it: `var result = Regex.Match(path, @"(.+?)(\.[^\.]+$|$)");` Hover the mouse over `result` and see what the method returned. That's what programming is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Group[1].Value`

```
string path = @"C:\PERSONAL\TEST\TESTFILE.PDF";
var match = Regex.Match(path, @"(.+?)(\.[^\.]+$|$)");
if(match.Success)
{
    var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

`match.Value` returns the `Captures.Value` which is the entire match

`match.Group[0]` always has the same value as `match.Value`

`match.Group[1]` return the first capture value

For example:

```
string path = @"C:\PERSONAL\TEST\TESTFILE.PDF";
var match = Regex.Match(path, @"(.+?)(\.[^\.]+$|$)");
if(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    // return the substring of the matching part
    //Output: C:\\PERSONAL\\TEST\\TESTFILE.PDF 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value)
    // always the same as match.Value
    //Output: C:\\PERSONAL\\TEST\\TESTFILE.PDF 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value)
    // return the first capture group which is (.+?) in this case
    //Output: C:\\PERSONAL\\TEST\\TESTFILE 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value)
    // return the second capture group which is (\.[^\.]+$|$) in this case
    //Output: .PDF 

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: It's `Groups[2].Value`, not `1`. `0` is the entire input string (because the two capturing groups together match the whole thing), `1` is the (unnecessary) first captured group, `2` is the second.

Comment: @Stefan Whoops, I mistook you for OP. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is on the right side of the string, tell the regex parser to work from the *end of the string to the beginning* by using the option `RightToLeft`. Which will significantly reduce the processing time as well as lessen the actual pattern needed.

The pattern below reads from left to right and says, give me everything that is not a `\` character (to consume/match up to the slash and not proceed farther) and start consuming up to a period.

```
Regex.Match(@"C:\PERSONAL\TEST\TESTFILE.PDF", 
            @"([^\\]+)\.", 
            RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
      .Groups[1].Value
```

Prints out

> TESTFILE

Answer (score 1):

Can be a bit shorter and greedier:

```
var name = Regex.Replace(@"C:\PERS.ONAL\TEST\TEST.FILE.PDF", @".*\\(.*)\..*", "$1"); // "TEST.FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.*(?=[.][^OS_FORBIDDEN_CHARACTERS]+$)
```

For Windows:

```
OS_FORBIDDEN_CHARACTERS = :\/\\\?"><\|
```

this is a sleight modification of:
[Regular expression get filename without extention from full filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815105/regular-expression-get-filename-without-extention-from-full-filepath)

If you are fine to match forbidden characters then simplest regex would be:

```
.*(?=[.].*$)
```